# Max inserted string should be selected for the output

Tags: php, html, mysql

I am beginner in PHP not experienced in OOP. I have already made database and store these data to my database by PHP and mysql.
But i can't make a output as max student vote for what person.Who will be selected for chairman!! 
Please help me.I am using xampp.

Here my code

```
<form method="post" action="">
        <table>
            <tr>
            <th>Roll</th>
            <th>Person</th>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <input style="text" name="Roll">
                </td>
                <td>
                    <select name="chairman">        
                <option value="Paul">Paul</option>
                <option  value="Jack">Jack</option>
                <option  value="Jons">Jons</option>

            </select>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit">

                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </form>
```

Comment: You action should point to the php file that is going to process this request. On PHP side, when you receive this request, you can access the values using $_POST

Comment: I have already done that . I have a column as 'person' and the data are stored as (Jack,Jack,Paul,Jons,Jons,Jack,Jack,Jack) for various roll number. But i want to get output as which person has been elected by max student for chairman post. :) 
Please help me

Comment: Oh, you could change your database structure to have a table that has 3 names in one column and vote count in another column.

Comment: Also you could use count function: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/counting-rows.html

Comment: It's not clear to me. :( Is there any selection method by which i can direct get  that output person which had been get max person selection? :(

Comment: Yes use a combination of MAX and COUNT. Rethink the way you designed your table.

Comment: <?php
        $vop=  mysql_connect('localhost','root','');
mysql_select_db("test",$paul);
if (isset($_POST['submit'])){
    $insert=  mysql_query("INSERT INTO lop (id, roll,person) 
    VALUES (NULL, $_POST[Roll],$_POST['chairman']) )";
    
}
?>

This is my database code.

Comment: Did you even bother to read the link I gave you?

Comment: Nope :) 
Trying :D :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First specify the form submit action (if you have specified it in your actual webpage, then not a problem)

Create the number of fields you need in your Database (depending upon the election candidates)

Then obtain the `select` value in the PHP and based on the value ,update the database fields.

```
<form method="post" action="your_PHP_file.php">
     <select name="chairman">        
            <option value="Paul">Paul</option>
            <option  value="Jack">Jack</option>
            <option  value="Jons">Jons</option>
     </select>
</form>
```

**your_PHP_file.php script**

```
//Use the essential steps to connect to your MySQL database
$getSelect = $_POST['chairman'];

if($getSelect == 'Paul'){
     //Increment the database value assigned for Paul
     mysql_query("UPDATE yourTable SET paul_id = paul_id+1 LIMIT 1");

     //Initially set the paul_id to '0'
}
else if($getSelect == 'Jack'){
     //Increment the database value assigned for Jack
}
if($getSelect == 'Jons'){
     //Increment the database value assigned for Jons
}
```

At last if you want to display the candidate with the largest amount of votes use something like this in the PHP.

```
//Connect to databse

$db_1 = mysql_auery("SELECT paul_id,jack_id,jons_id FROM yourTable WHERE 1");
$getRow = mysqli_fetch_array($db_1,MYSQLI_NUM);
$can_1 = $getRow[0];
$can_2 = $getRow[1];
$can_3 = $getRow[2];

if($can_1 > $can_2 && $can_1 > $can_3){
      //Display Paul is winner
}

else if($can_2 > $can_1 && $can_2 > $can_3){
      //Display Jack is winner
}

else{
     //Display Jons is winner
}
```

make necessary modifications to this code and use it in your webpage. This will work fine.